# How can I create an SSL connection for socket.io in nest.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ssl-certificate

|Greetings|

We are developing an application using nest.js and socket.io, and I'd like to know whether it's possible to create an SSL connection for this environment.

Here's the link to the repo: https://github.com/nokia/skilltree
( the latest attempts have been made in the David branch )

I tried this one, but the socket.io still doesn't use SSL connection:
https://blog.cloudboost.io/everything-about-creating-an-https-server-using-node-js-2fc5c48a8d4e
They suggest this:

```
var options = {
  key: key,
  cert: cert,
  ca: ca
};
var https = require('https');
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Another option that worked for our solution, was to setup a *Network Load Balancer* in front on the websocket server, with public certificates attached. This way, your NLB handles the SSL, and your websocket can work without having to configure https on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Nest takes an option object as second parameter, which also contains https options, like:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { 
    httpsOptions: {
      key: 'key',
      ca: 'ca',
      cert: 'cert',
    },
  });

await app.listen(3000);
```

So there should be no need to create the express instance yourself.
Haven't tested, but it should actually work. :)
See also: [HttpOptions Interface NestJs](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/interfaces/external/https-options.interface.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Spent entire day with exactly the same issue, here the best solution I could find:

```
const httpsOptions = {
    key: key,
    cert: cert,
    ca: ca
};
const expressInstance: express.Express = express();
const app: NestApplication = await NestFactory.create(
    MainModule, 
    expressInstance, 
    { httpsOptions }
);
await app.listen(Environment.PORT);
```

With this approach secure websockets work just fine for me